# Why an ObservableArrayMap cannot be passed to the included layout with android binding?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

When an ObservableArrayMap is passed to the included layout there is a compile error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find type element for ObservableArrayMap
>   file:D:....\layout\activity_home.xml
>   loc:35:54 - 35:56
>   ****\ data binding error ****

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
           <data>
               <import type="android.databinding.ObservableArrayMap"/>
               <variable name="map" type="ObservableArrayMap&lt;String, String&gt;"/>
           </data>
           <LinearLayout
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">
               <include layout="@layout/name"
                   bind:map="@{map}"/>
               <include layout="@layout/contact"
                   bind:map="@{map}"/>
           </LinearLayout>
        </layout>
```

Looks like the compiler doesn't recognize ObservableArrayMap type. Is there any other syntax to add type that I am missing?

Comment: It looks right to me. It must be a bug. Did you try: `<variable name="map" type="android.databinding.ObservableArrayMap&lt;String, String&gt;"/>`?

Comment: @GeorgeMount Still the same! I have reported it [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228994)

Comment: I tried this with Android Studio 2.3 canary 3 and it worked. I haven't tried with an older version. Maybe it was fixed?

Comment: @GeorgeMount Are you sure it worked in canary 3? I tried in 2.3 beta 1 and 2.3 canary 3 and the issue exists! Could you post the syntax that worked?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <import type="android.databinding.ObservableArrayMap" />
        <variable
            name="map"
            type="ObservableArrayMap&lt;String, String&gt;" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{map.text}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_main"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Note that the IDE shows red for the variable, but it compiles and runs anyway.

-- Edit --

There is a bug in Android Studio as of 2.3 canary 3 related to including the `ObservableArrayMap`. You can work around it until it is fixed in a later release by using a non-generic variable in the included layout. Here is my included layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <import type="android.databinding.ObservableMap" />
        <variable
            name="map"
            type="ObservableMap" />
    </data>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{(String)map[`text`]}"/>
</layout>
```

Thanks for finding this!

Comment: Could you try adding <include layout="@layout/sub_layout"  bind:map="@{map}" ></include> The error occurs only when there is an included layout and bound with a variable